# PHP run static method before each static function

Tags: php

I want to be able to call a function automatically before any function is invoked. The problem with __callStatic is that it only runs if the method does not exist.

See the code below.

I want to make always_run() run before any function that was called in the static class.

```
class Test {

    public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters){
        echo __CLASS__ . "::" . $method;
        if (method_exists(__CLASS__, $method)) {
            self::always_run();
            forward_static_call_array(array(__CLASS__,$method),$args);
        }
    }

    public static function always_run() {
        echo "always_run";
    }

    public static function my_func() {
        echo "myfunc was called";
    }

}

Test::my_func();
// OUTPUT: always_run myfunc wascalled
```

Comment: you could put `self::always_run()` inside `my_func()` or convert all your static calls to use `__callStatic` as a type of router.

Comment: self::always_run() inside my_func, imagine i am calling 100 funcs, I want to avoid that. That's the whole point. As a type of router? what do you mean?

Comment: It is a bad design, if something like this is needed. However, You can try to make a "pack" function that as an attribute has a static function that You want to run. For example: $object::runMethod('methodname'); and in the runMethod run what You want before, or after...

Comment: have you considered observer pattern for this?

Answer (score 5):

Creating static classes such as this that have a global state is always bad design. You should really just be creating object, then you can run any sort of set up code you need in the constructor.

```
class Test
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Code run only once when the object is constructed.
    }
}
```

Static state makes such classes difficult to test and maintain. Static classes cannot be mocked, so code that depends on the class cannot be independently tested.

Here's an article to help you out: https://r.je/static-methods-bad-practice.html

Comment: The constructor runs only once. Static is not always bad design. :)

Comment: @user2867106, when you come to the situation when you need `a static that runs before all other static methods`, you can bet it's a bad design.

Comment: well, that does not mean "static classes are bad design". I did not come to this situation, it came to me :) I am extending a WP plugin and it has limitations.

Comment: I updated the answer with a little more detail and link to an article that will explain it much better than I could here.

Answer (score 3):

You can make the methods private:

```
class Test {

    public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters){
        echo __CLASS__ . "::" . $method;
        if (method_exists(__CLASS__, $method)) {
            self::always_run();
            forward_static_call_array(array(__CLASS__,$method),$parameters);
        }
    }

    private static function always_run() {
        echo "always_run";
    }

    private static function my_func() {
        echo "myfunc was called";
    }

}

Test::my_func();
```

A bit of a hack really, but this isnt really an ideal situation

Comment: what is "hack" about this ? O.o it's more of a "hook" than a hack ...

Comment: + since PHP **5.6** you can even do just `self::$method(...$parameters);` (feature added docs - https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.variadics ) , **also** you should probably **`return`** the result of the forwarded call no matter how it's done...